# Visual studio 2015 Android with NDK - Build error GenerateAndroidAntScripts

Tags: android, android-ndk, msbuild, visual-studio-2015

I have imported my android eclipse project using the new extension
https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/53e6e65b-fa0f-411a-a98d-7911009537ac

My C++ code seem to compile well but I have error with GenerateAndroidAntScripts. Here's the output file:

```
    2>------ Build started: Project: IRCM-CLAP-masterPackaging, Configuration: Debug ARM ------
    2>  ANDROID_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk
    2>  ANT_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Visual Studio\Apps\apache-ant-1.9.3\
    2>  JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\
    2>  NDK_ROOT=C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\AndroidNDK\android-ndk-r10e\

    2>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\MDD\Android\V140\Android.Common.targets(264,5): error MSB4018: The "GenerateAndroidAntScripts" task failed unexpectedly.
    2>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\MDD\Android\V140\Android.Common.targets(264,5): error MSB4018: System.NotSupportedException: The given path's format is not supported.
    2>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\MDD\Android\V140\Android.Common.targets(264,5): error MSB4018:    at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
    2>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\MDD\Android\V140\Android.Common.targets(264,5): error MSB4018:    at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
    2>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\MDD\Android\V140\Android.Common.targets(264,5): error MSB4018:    at System.IO.StreamReader..ctor(String path, Encoding encoding, Boolean detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean checkHost)
    2>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\MDD\Android\V140\Android.Common.targets(264,5): error MSB4018:    at System.IO.StreamReader..ctor(String path)
    2>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\MDD\Android\V140\Android.Common.targets(264,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.CPPTasks.GenerateAndroidAntScripts.StringReplaceAndWrite(String inputFile, String defaultFile, String outputPath, List`1 replacementTable, Boolean incremental)
    2>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\MDD\Android\V140\Android.Common.targets(264,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.CPPTasks.GenerateAndroidAntScripts.Execute()
    2>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\MDD\Android\V140\Android.Common.targets(264,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
    2>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\MDD\Android\V140\Android.Common.targets(264,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.d__26.MoveNext()
    ========== Build: 1 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

This seem like a directory problem, anyone can help?

Comment: I feel the question should include more information in order to let people help you. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Could you enable diagnostic or detailed build output so we can get more information? It's under Debug->Options->Projects and Solutions -> Build and Run, change the "MSBuild project build output verbosity" to Detailed.

Answer (score 2):

I've gotten the same problem.

It was fixed when I excluded all .properties files from the project.